# Asp.net Mvc4 GridMvc convert DateTime in columns.Add()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using GridMvc 3.0.0 in my ASP.NET MVC4 application. 
I added column to my grid. The field is in DateTime format:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(c => c.Date).Titled("Date").Filterable(true);
    }).WithPaging(5).Sortable(true).Selectable(false)
```

It reads data from SQL, so i get `27/11/14 12:00:00 AM` this date.
All i want is to convert it to dd/MM/yyyy, i tried to do this way:

```
columns.Add(c => DateTime.Parse(c.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Titled("Date").Filterable(true);
```

but it did not work.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `27/11/14 12:00:00 AM` isn't already a `DateTime`? I strongly suspect you just wanna format your `DateTime` like `c.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead of parsing operation.

Comment: And `DateTime.Parse` doesn't even have an overload like that. It only has `DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)` which takes 3 parameters.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but i can't call c.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) in view either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid this issue is to add one derived property in your viewmodel :

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string DisplayedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

and then call this new property instead of the first one :

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(c => c.DisplayedDate)
            .Titled("Date").Filterable(true);
    }).WithPaging(5).Sortable(true).Selectable(false)
```

Comment: Below you find a perfect solution.

Answer (score 9):

bit late but you can use the format function like

```
col.Add(c => c.Date).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Titled("Your Date");
```